Nursery Rhymes message :
Jack and Jill went up the hill.
A rhyme that kindergarten kids are taught ends like this:

Jack fell down and broke his crown,
And Jill came tumbling after.




A friend believes that every renowned rhyme has a message to share. I couldn't see a positive message in this rhyme that would benefit children. Can you?

How does this question involve learning English or how it works?

I’m voting to close this question because it’s off-topic.

@PaulTanenbaum Children in non native English speaking countries start learning English by these rhymes. It addresses an important question what and why something should be taught?

@James Mathai: Surely that can't be true! Why on earth would anyone think learning centuries-old children's nursery rhymes could be a useful way to acquire competence in current English language? To the extent that British children are taught things like that (not much, I'd have thought), it's not to introduce them to the language - it's part of our cultural heritage. I'm pretty sure I never learned the lyrics / tune of Frère Jacques in my French lessons at school. Why would I have needed to know what Sonnez les matines means for elementary French? I think that was music!

It's Off Topic for ELL, but here are 3 possible "origins / meanings". 1) The French Revolution (Jack & Jill are Louis XVI and Marie Antoinette), 2) King Charles's Tax (a "jack" was a standard measure of about a quarter pint, the volume of which Charles unilaterally reduced while levying the same tax), and 3) "Jack and Jill" are just "generic commoners" inappropriately trying to rise above their station in life. They should know their place (at the bottom of a stable hierarchical society).

@FumbleFingers It is always debated what message is given to the kids. Is it positive? Some rhymes have been modified to make it positive like - None for the naughty boy changed to One for the good boy (Ba ba black sheep)

@JamesMathai: We obviously learned different versions! I never heard of anyone "sanitizing" Baa Baa Black Sheep from naughty boy to good boy. The only version I ever knew was one for the little boy who lives down the lane. For centuries both children and some parents have transposed the consonants of one for the master, one for the dame to one for the maid. But it's really nothing to do with learning English.

And most nursery rhymes aren't "positive" anyway. Stereotypically, Ring-A-Ring-A-Roses is about the Black Death.

@FumbleFingers l was referring to this: (from net) - More recently the rhyme has been alleged to have a connection to the slave trade, particularly in the southern United States. This explanation was advanced during debates over political correctness and the use and reform of nursery rhymes in the 1980s, but has no supporting historical evidence.

@FumbleFingers - when I was at school we naughty boys learned a ribald version: Jack and Jill/Went up the hill/To fetch a pail of water/I don't know what they did up there/But they came down with a daughter. Imagine my surprise just now (via Google) to see a theory that is very similar (except it was a son).

We learnt the original Bah bah black sheep and not the modified one.- In the original version there was 'none for the little boy who lives down the lane'.  https://nurseryrhymes.info/baa-baa-black-sheep/

@JamesMathai: I don't get that. The consonant transposition from dame (I assume the "original") to made seems natural enough, given that the former would hardly figure in the average child's (or parent's) vocabulary in C20. But since it's always three bags full, what happens to the leftover one if the little boy doesn't get it? I see that Wikipedia says The words have barely changed in two and a half centuries. It does actually give the original from 1744, then says "none" appeared in the next known version in 1765, but no further mention of how that could make sense.

...perhaps whoever put together the 1765 printing of Mother Goose's Melody was conflating boys, toes, and pigs - This little piggy had none.

@FumbleFingers - The farmers had to earn a living. Taken from the link - King Edward I introduced a tax on wool, where the proceeds of wool was shared three ways, between:
the King
the Church
the farmer
In the original version there was 'none for the little boy who lives down the lane'. A version of the rhyme from 1744 went:

But like I just told you, Wikipedia cites the earliest version (1744) with one for the little boy, and explicitly points out that in the next written instance (Mother Goose's Melody, 1765), the only change was from one to none. And this usage chart shows that none never really caught on (presumably because like I said, it simply doesn't make sense).

...if you repeat my usage chat with my instead of the [little boy, it's also obvious that nobody particularly liked the former. Once it became widespread, that was always bound to change, imho. After the great Victorian "urbanization", ordinary people just wouldn't talk about my master, my dame.

You're missing a very commonly added second verse, which provides the 'positive' message, I guess - Jack went to his cosy home and got better using the helpful 'medication' available there:

Jack and Jill Went up the hill
To fetch a pail of water
Jack fell down
and broke his crown
And Jill came tumbling after.
Up Jack got
And home did trot,
As fast as he could caper;
Went to bed
To mend his head
With vinegar and brown paper.


Also, in versions, I've heard, Jill laughs at Jack's misfortune and is "whipped 'cross her knee" for it.

@AndyBonner Didn't Jill tumble down ? (picture)

@JamesMathai But didn't "break her crown." See this Wikipedia article for the history of the rhyme, including a 1791 version that suggests a "maxim" that "the more you think of dying, the better you will live." But also note that discussing the deeper meanings or history of poems is not on topic in this stack exchange; that would be getting into literary analysis rather than language.
